# Does $\min\{x_1x_3+x_2^2 | x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^4 = 4\}$ has an optimal solution?

Tags: analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Does $\min\{x_1x_3+x_2^2 | x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^4 = 4\}$ has an optimal solution?

I think continuous function over closed and bounded domain has an optimal solution but I am not sure. Can anyone give me some clarification? Thank you in advance !

Comment: @almagest: your solution does not meet the constraint.[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+a*c%2Bb%5E2,+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E4+%3D+4) comes to a different conclusion.

Comment: Hi. Its not correct since $x_3^4$ not power of 2

Comment: Sorry, I misread $x_3^4$ as $x_3^2$. My comment about $x_2=0$ is still correct. Are you happy with Lagrange multipliers? It is easy if you use that technique.